# Why isn't Text to Speech working?

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech

I am trying to make an app where a phone can speak Chinese text inside an EditText. It works fine on a phone with API 19, when I test it on a phone with API 23, when I press the button that speaks the text, nothing comes out. How come? (The sound is at full volume on the phone and it works for English text.
P.S. If I change the language to French and the text to "Bonjour", it works.)

My code is this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText subject;
    Button submit;
    TextToSpeech t1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        subject = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.subject);
        submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);

        t1 = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            public void onInit(int status) {

                t1.setLanguage(Locale.SIMPLIFIED_CHINESE);
            }

        });
// The button is called submit. The toast is there just to make sure that the t1.speak started to run.
        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 20) {
                    t1.setLanguage(Locale.SIMPLIFIED_CHINESE);
                    String utteranceId = this.hashCode() + "";
                    t1.speak(subject.getText().toString(), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, utteranceId);
                    Context context = getApplicationContext();
                    CharSequence text = "Hello toast!";
                    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                    toast.show();
                } else {
                    t1.setLanguage(Locale.SIMPLIFIED_CHINESE);
                    t1.speak(subject.getText().toString(), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                }
            }


        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, Samsung Text-to-Speech does not support Chinese. You need to change your Text-to-Speech to Google. Then, it started working for me.